# React Navigation 5 popToTop with no animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Does anyone know how to pop to the top of a stack without animation in React Navigation 5?

My use case is that I have a drawer sidebar, and when the user taps on an item, I want to navigate to that stack, but pop to the top of that stack, resetting the navigation.  I have it working with the following code, but it animates and is an unexpected UX.

```js
navigation.dispatch({
  ...StackActions.popToTop(), 
  source: currentRoute.key, 
  target: targetStack.key
});
```

Any way to do that without animation?

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
navigation.popToTop({immediate: true})
```

source : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3480

Comment: That is for React Navigation v1.  I am using v5 which does not have that option.  It is exactly what I want though, that would be nice!  That's in fact how I did this in RN4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue... A workaround is to disable the `transitionSpec` animation on `close`:

```
transitionSpec: {
    open: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
    close: {
        animation: 'timing',
        config: {
            duration: 0,
        },
    },
}
```

It works fine but the problem is that if you use the `Back` button from the certain screen, the animation will be disabled, too :/

Of course, this is related to your UX and maybe this will not be a problem :)